# Are $\sin$ and $\cos$ the only functions whose derivatives are equal to each other up to a sign?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Are $\sin$ and $\cos$   the only functions that satisfy the following relationship: 
$$  x'(t) = -y(t)$$
 and
$$ y'(t) = x(t)
$$

Comment: Of course $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ are each other's derivatives *without* the sign difference, a situation which is easily understood by writing all four functions out in term of (potentially complex) exponentials.

Comment: You could also open up more solutions by allowing more than two functions in the cycle.

Answer (score 63):

The relationships $x'(t) = -y(t)$ and $y'(t) = x(t)$ imply
$$x''(t) = -y'(t) = -x(t)$$
i.e.
$$x''(t) = -x(t)$$
which only has solutions $x(t) = A \cos t + B \sin t$ for some constants $A$, $B$. For a given choice of the constants we then get $y(t) = -x'(t) = A \sin t - B \cos t$.

Answer (score 15):

Basically, yes, they are. More precisely: if $x,y\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions such that $x'=-y$ and that $y'=x$, then there are numbers $k$ and $\omega$ such that$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):x(t)=k\cos(t+\omega)\text{ and }y(t)=k\sin(t+\omega).$$

Answer (score 14):

Your system is also satisfied by
$$
x(t)=y(t)=0
$$

Comment: I don't see what utility these sort of obvious edge cases have. Given that it's  clearly against the spirit of the question, I would think a comment is more than enough.

Comment: 'Edge' cases are important in mathematics. It's no more an 'edge' case than saying $2\sin$ and $2\cos$ are solutions. It's completely in the spirit of the question, it provides an example of a solution different to the trigonometric functions enquired about. @md2perpe +1

Comment: Note that this is the same solution (A sin or cos t ) with A = 0, rather than an edge case

Answer (score 9):

We also have that relationship for  $2\sin$ and $2\cos$

Comment: Well for all $k\sin x$ and $k\cos x$

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you can set:
$$
  x\left(t\right) = \exp\left(-i \cdot t\right)\\
  y\left(t\right) = i\cdot\exp\left(-i \cdot t\right)\\
  i = \sqrt{-1}
$$